# Showing a UTF16-LE encoded string in textview for Android

Tags: android, textview

I have a UTF-16LE encoded string that comes from a server. I would like to print that string in Textview of my activity. However, the string prints with spaces in between them. So, "Hello" prints as "H e l l o" and doesn't look all that nice in my screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you receiving it? Just dumping a UTF-16LE byte stream into a String would result in the kind of output you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. How would I convert it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a stream (or array of `byte`s) containing a UTF-16LE encoded string.

```
String str0 = "Hello, I am a UTF-16LE encoded String";
byte[] utf16le = str.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

If you do not convert these back & stating the character set used you will be producing a string containing a lot of 0-bytes (UTF-16LE is, obviously, 16-bit) in your resulting String.

```
String wrong = new String(utf16le); // This will produce crap with \0:s in it.
String correct = new String(utf16le, "UTF-16LE"); // This will be the actual string.
```

*Note*: If you dump crap String:s like these into a TextView in ICS it will remove the garbage for you and not print "H e l l o".

Comment: On the second line of your first paragraph of code. You call the getBytes() function on an variable named "str" shouldn't that be "str0" ?